# Mesh lines on SmoothDensityHistogram

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions, legending

I am making a plot with SmoothDensityHistogram that looks like this:

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 10],MeshStyle -> Red, Mesh -> 3, PlotLegends ->Placed[BarLegend[Automatic,LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.3], 30, FontFamily -> "Arial"}],   After]]
```

I would need some help on the following: 
- I would like to decide which Mesh lines are shown and indicate their value on it;
- in the BarLegend, multiply all the values that are shown by a given number or, equivalently, normalize the scale to be between 0 and 1.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get more control is to build your own version of `SmoothDensityHistogram` using `DensityPlot` and `ContourPlot`.

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 10];
pdf = PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data], {x, y}];

dp = DensityPlot[
   pdf,
   {x, -3, 3},
   {y, -3, 3},
   PlotLegends -> Automatic
   ];

cp = ContourPlot[
   pdf,
   {x, -3, 3},
   {y, -3, 3},
   Contours -> 4,
   ContourShading -> None,
   ContourLabels -> True
   ];

Show[dp, cp]
```

[image: Plot example]

To multiply all values by a number, you can multiply the PDF by that number.

The functions have options that can help you achieve higher quality in the figure. `DensityPlot` has an option called `PlotPoints` for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 10];
pdf = PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[data]];

sdh = SmoothDensityHistogram[data, MeshStyle -> Red, Mesh -> 3, 
   Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, 
      LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.3], 30, FontFamily -> "Arial"}], After]];
```

Extract the mesh lines from `sdh` and find the associated pdf values:

```
mesh = DeleteDuplicates @ Round[Cases[Normal@sdh, Line[x_] :> pdf[x[[1]]], All], .001];
```

Post-process `sdh` to inject the (*undocumented*) sub-option `"StyledContours"` into the legend:

```
styledcontours = Method -> "StyledContours" -> Thread[{mesh, Directive[Thick, Red]}];

sdh /. b_BarLegend :> Append[b, styledcontours]
```

[image]

To add text labels to the mesh lines using another round of post-processing:

```
epilog = Cases[Normal @ sdh, Line[x_] :> 
    Text[ Round[pdf[x[[1]]], .001], BSplineFunction[x]@.5], All];

Show[sdh /. b_BarLegend :> Append[b, styledcontours], Epilog -> epilog]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can construct a `ContourPlot` using `mesh` as `Contours` and the option `ContourLabels` and `Show` it with `sdh`:

```
cp = ContourPlot[pdf[{x, y}],, {x, -1, 2}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   Contours -> DeleteDuplicatesBy[Round[#, .01] &]@mesh, 
   ContourStyle -> Red, ContourLabels -> All, ContourShading -> None, 
   PlotRange -> All];

Show[sdh /. b_BarLegend :> Append[b, styledcontours], cp]
```

[image]

You can also change the list of labeled ticks in `BarLegend` using

```
Show[sdh /. b_BarLegend :> Append[b, {styledcontours, 
     "Ticks" -> DeleteDuplicatesBy[Round[#, .01] &]@mesh}],
  cp]
```

[image]